append rows to csv file, using apache nifi
using Apache nifi 2.0.0, i don't see an option to append rows to an existing csv file.
My setup:

some generator, creating a json-string with an array of records
SplitJson to create single records
ConvertRecord to read the json input and create csv records.

RecordReader: JsonTreeReader
RecordWriter: CSVRecordSetWriter


UpdateAttribute to define the filename
PutFile to write to the file.

Unfortunatly there is no 'append' option for the Conflict Resolution Strategy. So: how to append rows? Do I have to implement a TextAppender processor?

You can use the ReplaceText Processor in Nifi
Use the following Properties:
Replacement Strategy  -  Append
Replacement Value - Your Row value to insert
Evaluation Method-  Entire text

i see. Do you know if the whole existing file will be read and written in the process?
